# Return record with highest ID from multiple columns

Tags: mysql

My table is receiving coordinates and latitudes + other informaton from two GPS devices. Everytime the GPS sends new iformation, it increments the ID with one. I want a query that takes the highest ID(last received information) from device 1 and device 2 so I can show it my GoogleMap application. Can someone help me with the query?
The rows in my table looks like this:

```
Table
===============================
ID    LAT     LNG      DeviceID
1     #       #        1
2     #       #        1
3     #       #        1 
4     #       #        1  <---This
1     #       #        2
2     #       #        2
3     #       #        2  
4     #       #        2  <---This
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get id column and DeviceID you should [group](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) by id, and select max id in a groups.

```
SELECT MAX(ID), DeviceID 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY DeviceID
```

But in mysql you're allowed to not aggregate non-group-by columns, in which case mysql just returns the first row. So first you need to order it, then group

```
select DeviceId, ANY_VALUE (LAT), ANY_VALUE(LNG), MAX(id)
from 
    (select * 
     from table 
     order by `DeviceID`, id desc, lat, lng)  x
group by `DeviceId`
```

Or you can get max(id) and DeviceId then use Join to get other rows.

```
select positions.id, positions.lat, positions.lng, positions.DeviceId
from positions
inner join 
    (select max(id) as mId, DeviceId 
     from positions
     group by DeviceId) maxt on (positions.id = maxt.mId and positions.DeviceId = maxt.DeviceId)
```

Comment: you miss the device id in the select.

Comment: So, I tried running the query, bit I get this error: "Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'lgpsno.positions.latitude' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: @ojjaman You can  disable only_full_group_by mode, or run query with ANY_VALUE

Comment: Ok, so I used ANY_VALUE at all the coumns I wanted except for ID and DeviceID. It worked great! Thank you @Valentin

Comment: The only problem now is that the lat/long does not belong to the given ID. When I execute the query I get latitudes and longitudes from ID=1, DeviceId=2 but should be ID=4(highest),DeviceID=2. Any fix on that?

Comment: @ojjaman Have you tried to set sql_mode = '' and use last query?

Comment: I have tried to do it, but Im not sure if I succeded. I'm using PHPMyadmin remote server

Comment: Is there another way to do without disabling **only_full_group_by**?

Comment: @Valentin Tried you suggestion but it gives me this error: "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 'DeviceID',id     desc,latitude,longitude) GROUP BY 'DeviceID'`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM positions ORDER BY 'deviceId',id DESC,latitude,longitude) x GROUP BY 'deviceId'`. It still gives me this error: "_Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'x.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause_

Comment: @ojjaman ok, can you try with any_value ? I've updated answer

Comment: @Valentin it gives me the correct id and deviceId, but the wrong latitude/longitude. Looks like I get the latitude and longitude from the first id

Comment: @ojjaman I've updated answer. Try to use join. It should works

Comment: @Valentin tried the last query, but it gives me "Unknown column 'test.id' in 'field list'"

Comment: @ojjaman test is my table, sorry. I've updated answer, try it

Comment: @Valentin thought I tried positions, but looks like I didn't - It works great now. Thanks alot for all the help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
SELECT DeviceID, max(ID) from Table GROUP BY DeviceID
```

You will have one row for each device id